# Can you swap VisualStateManager for MultiTrigger in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpftoolkit, visualstatemanager, multitrigger

This really relates to creating a library that works across both WPF and Silverlight. The [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=22567) includes an implementation of the VisualStateManager included with Silverlight, and if the VisualStateManager can do what the MultiTrigger in WPF does, that solves my problem.

I just found an [article on MSDN Blogs discussing the use of VisualStateManager and Triggers](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx), but I'm still not sure whether or not VisualStateManager can be used as a replacement for MultiTriggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VisualStateManager cannot completely replace WPF's MultiTrigger. WPF's MultiTrigger has built-in support for conditions. The VisualStateManager only supports states. While states may seem like conditions at first glimpse, this is not entirely true. For instance, in WPF you could use a MultiTrigger that only runs if the content of a Button says "OK". However, this is not really a button state, because of this, the VisualStateManager cannot be used in this situation.

I hope this is helpful,
Chad Campbell - Author of Silverlight 2 in Action